# Получить теги без потока в bass.dll + Qt

Tags: c++, qt, bass.dll

Здравствуйте. В Bass.net есть чудесная функция BassTags.BASS_TAG_GetFromFile, которая позволяет получать теги не требуя потока. В модуле tags.dll я не нашел такого, ибо он позволяет только выводить теги с заданным форматов текущего потока. 
Как можно вытянуть ID3v1/ID3v2 теги из аудиофайла желательно средствали bass?